# I have put @Transactional in method still it commits the transaction before rollback

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

How to achieve transaction management in Spring

My methods are as below

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@Override
public InwardDTO saveEntity(InwardDTO entity) throws Exception {
    try {
        costCalculation(entity);
        InwardDTO dto = super.saveEntity(entity);
        addStock(dto.getDetails(), dto.getId());
        return dto;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private void addStock(Set<InwardDetailsDTO> argDetailsDTOSet, Long argInwardId) throws RuntimeException {
    String SUBMODULE = getModuleNameForLog() + " [addStock()] ";

    if (1 == 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Test Case");
    }
}
```

Logs are like,

```
2020-02-29 15:01:14.210 TRACE 14504 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
Hibernate: insert into tbl_inward_chemical (date, invoice_number, is_deleted, party_id, po_id, pre_inward_id_id, remark, slip, total_amount, total_weight) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into tbl_inward_details_chemical (inward_id, is_deleted, is_pass, party_moisture_id, party_ph_id, party_price, party_purity_id, party_solubility_id, party_weight, product_name_id, received_moisture_id, received_ph_id, received_price, received_purity_id, received_solubility_id, received_weight, total_price) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into tbl_inward_details_chemical (inward_id, is_deleted, is_pass, party_moisture_id, party_ph_id, party_price, party_purity_id, party_solubility_id, party_weight, product_name_id, received_moisture_id, received_ph_id, received_price, received_purity_id, received_solubility_id, received_weight, total_price) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-02-29 15:01:14.216 TRACE 14504 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
2020-02-29 15:01:14.216 TRACE 14504 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [com.alignedorg.chemical.inward.service.InwardService.saveEntity] after exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Case
2020-02-29 15:01:14.216 TRACE 14504 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute    : Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Case
2020-02-29 15:01:14.216 TRACE 14504 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute    : Winning rollback rule is: RollbackRuleAttribute with pattern [java.lang.RuntimeException]
2020-02-29 15:01:14.222 ERROR 14504 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.a.core.utillity.log.ApplicationLogger  :  [ Inward Controller ]  [SAVE] Test Case

java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Case
```

In this transactional is always commited before rollback of addStock Method ...
In logs it is showing like transaction is rollback but entry is saved in DB...

Comment: I don't see any `@Transactional`. Can yo paste more code?

Comment: remove the catch try-catch block. Also, you are rollbackFor = Exception.class and throwing RuntimeException.

Comment: @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)

    @Override

    public InwardDTO saveEntity(InwardDTO entity) throws Exception {

        try {

            costCalculation(entity);

            InwardDTO dto = super.saveEntity(entity);

            addStock(dto.getDetails(), dto.getId());

            return dto;

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            throw ex;

        }
    }

Comment: still not working @dassum

Comment: share the revised code also change propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS to propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED

Comment: updated at code section @dassum

Comment: remove the try-catch block your exception is getting suppressed. Also , remove the throws rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class clause and throws clause at method level.

Comment: Are you using MySQL with MyISAM storage engine by any chance?

Comment: I am using MYSQL @Josef

Comment: @Thakkar Can you also check your table engine please? You can do it using this mysql query: `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'tbl_inward_chemical'` - the `engine` column should contain the value.

Answer (score 1):

Spring transaction bean required list:

1.JdbcTemplate

```java
@Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate creatJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

2.DataSource

```java
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource creatDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    ds.setUrl(url);
    ds.setUsername(username);
    ds.setPassword(password);
    return ds;
}
```

3.TransactionManager

```java
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager creatTransactionManager(DataSource  dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

4.`@EnableTransactionManagement` above one `@Configuration Class` to activate `TxManager`

5.Use JdbcTemplate's instance(`@Autowired`) in `DaoImplements` to execute sql with `query()` || `update()` method

Answer (score 1):

In case the table storage engine is `MyISAM`: This engine does not support transactions. The correct one should be `InnoDB`.

If you are using automatic creation of tables from Hibernate: I would recommend writing your own migrations and using tool like [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) do manage those. It's a bit more work but you will have total control over how your tables look like.